# How is it possible I can't no longer create a new site collection in SharePoint Online? I'm a global administrator

Tags: sharepoint-online

I really don't know what causes this issue. This is the message I got everytime I tried to create a new one.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to close your browser, clear the cache and try again? or try from different pc?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause could be there is already a private Office 365 Group with the same name has created and your account has not permission on this group (not an owner or a member of the group).

Navigation to Admin Center -> Groups.

For example: a "testGroup" Office 365 Group. The Owner is a user (not your account).

[image]

Then, create a site with same name in the address:

[image]

The error shows up.

[image]

Several Solutions:

1. Change the address to another.
2. Add your account as an owner or a member of this Office 365 group.
3. Ask the owner or the member of the group to create the site.

Similar issue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fccdd3af-24c0-44d2-8d9e-f00a64ac7d19/access-denied-to-sharepoint-online-administrator?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

If this answer helps you, please accept it as the best answer.